# Number of ways to color objects, with a lower limit on the number of colors used.

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

What is the number of ways to color $m$ distinct objects using $n$ colors such that at least $k$ colors are used?

For example, for $n=4, m=2, k=2$, the answer is

$$\binom{4}{2} \cdot 2! = 12$$

Here it is straight-forward as $k=m$.
How do I solve when $k < m$?

Here are special cases: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592391/number-of-ways-to-color-n-objects-with-4-colors-if-all-colors-must-be-used-at-le) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591126/number-of-ways-to-color-n-objects-with-3-colors-if-colors-must-be-used-once?rq=1)

Comment: Answer the question for *exactly* $k$ colors used.  Add up the results for each amount of colors used.  For *exactly* $k$, break the $m$ objects into $k$ nonempty groups using Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind in ${m\brace k}$ ways and then pick which $k$ colors were used for each group in $n\frac{k}{~}$ ways (*falling factorial*).  This gives a grand total of $\sum\limits_{i=k}^n{m\brace i}n\frac{i}{~}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks it does the job . But can you suggest more efficient computation. Computing stirling2 is $O(n^2)$ both memory and time and looping it makes it $O(n^3)$ time . I can afford O(N) or $O(N∗logX)$ time and $O(N)$ memory.

Comment: @JMoravitz Stirling2 can be done in [O(n log n)](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/30049) but that wont suffice. I need the overall complexity after looping to be something like that.

Comment: @hardmath this is open-ended question. There is no right or wrong approch. $O(n)$ or $O(n.logn)$ or $O(n)$ all are welcome obviously somenone who comes up with O(n) will be apprecated more. JMoravitz 's approach was nice but Mike Earnest's was more efficient and hence appreciated  more.

Comment: Open-ended questions are natural.  I voted to close because the body of your Question does not contain a problem statement.  Your title does a good job of setting up the problem (necessarily in a terse way), and your Comments above mention a goal of complexity.  At a minimum you could bring these ideas into the body of the Question.  Readers could then more easily contribute responses using your notation and terminology.

Comment: @hardmath comment is not meant to be a goal. but guideline. For any problem there is always a brute force solution. but that doesn't mean posting that as answer will get accepted. That may be accepted uptil there is a better solution. The Tick will always change as better and better solutions get posted. Secondly Will repeating title in the body make you reopen the question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A_i$ be the set of colorings which do not use the $i^{th}$ color. We want to count the number of colorings which use at least $k$ colors, which means there are at most $n-k$ values of $i$ for which the coloring is in $A_i$. Using a generalization of the inclusion-exclusion principle presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/362516), equation (8), we get
$$
\begin{align}
\text{# colorings with at least $k$ colors}
&=\text{# colorings in at most $n-k$ of the sets $A_i$}
\\&=\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^{j-(n-k)}\binom{n}{j}\binom{j-1}{n-k}|A_1\cap \dots \cap A_j|
\end{align}
$$
The case $j=0$ of this sum requires special attention. In this case, we get $(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}0\binom{-1}{n-k}$ times the size of the empty intersection. The empty intersection is just the whole universe of colorings, of which there are $n^m$. Also, $\binom{-1}{n-k}=(-1)^{n-k}$, so this summand is just $n^m$. Furthermore, for $1\le j \le n-k$, we have $\binom{j-1}{n-k}=0$, so we can omit these. Finally, $|A_1\cap \dots \cap A_j|=(n-j)^m$, since there are $j$ fewer colors available. Therefore, we can write this as
$$
\begin{align}
\text{# colorings with at least $k$ colors}
  &=n^m+\sum_{j=n-k+1}^n(-1)^{j-(n-k)}\binom nj\binom{j-1}{n-k}(n-j)^m
%\\&=n^m+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(-1)^{j-k}\binom nj\binom{n-j-1}{n-k}j^m
\end{align}
$$
This summation can be computed in $O(n\log m)$ time, as long as you pre-compute all of the binomial coefficients involved, and use exponentiation by squaring to find $(n-j)^m$. To quickly do the pre-computation, these identities are quite helpful:
$$
\binom{n}{j+1}=\frac{n-j}{j+1}\binom{n}{j}\qquad 
\binom{j}{n-k}=\frac{j}{j-(n-k)}\binom{j-1}{n-k}
$$
**Edit** After several edits, this is now correct. [This Python code](https://tio.run/##hVPBjpswFLzzFVP1EEigG7ZSK0VLjpV66Q9sVxFhTRaMn5Gxta128@3pswskUSOVQ2KGN@OZMfS/7Yumz6fTs6hRabWPKZXJJgJfTQ3CA9YbGGGdIawnWOKhuMAliuL88B5LRrag@fmoC8pkEqau8CxPZZYnzCLc3UFGkfdCTu0q3WnT0GFgspptfcQPp/bCoHZU2UbTgBobPKonZFs80hNeX4QReDcloX7HtmBNTyyryikUvM1yCRWgWhu0aAg8exAxIWPrK@Ts1f@NO57JqwIxe10u4zajlfSmp3DtfNOySlBgMQ8G2ZZJ6jJ8EIyi2miFxgpjte4GNKrXxqI3@tlV9kYVu71xVlwVMuVaz5GmaZ9slIrHhEnKBnpRWiaoi3x8cJ2geBA2nthJEro7z1z1kN8IQztV/mLhL5EaV185IRviftS/ZvL0L8E3nWLCoGZw9OcV5PmUbpxOc/uFwYfiv@1NV88DNq4X36nSxojKcrbBdda/TQTf75s6@p15QbyQfiGPnxZJFE3cb9oo15UoD0aIAa9N13E1zpbdJOajlIz@pNx/Q@FDIv/zFqpg3YCrAIUijovkdPoD) serves as a sanity check.

Comment: Thanks . can you  help me understand a bit may be by walking through an example. It's not very simple to understand. I will accept the answer once I understand this clearly (and also clean up these comments once done). "which means there are at most n−k values of i for which the coloring is in $A_{i}$"..what does it mean ? to compute $A_{i}$ you are skipping the i-th colour right, so out of remaining (n-1) colours any one color can occur (n-k) times at most right?

Comment: @JackBernardo I don't want to have a conversation in the comments, so let's talk in this chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137878/mike-earnest-and-jack-bernardo