# Number of ways to color n objects with 4 colors if all colors must be used at least once

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I have seen, and solved the following problem:

How many ways to color n objects with 3 colors $\{A, B, C\}$, if all colors must be used at least once.
$\require{enclose}$
The answer is as follows:

$$3^n-{{3}\choose{2}}\cdot2^n + {{3}\choose{1}}\cdot1^n$$
Because the number of forbidden colorings is:

$${{3}\choose{2}}\cdot2^n - {{3}\choose{1}}\cdot1^n$$

The overall answer then reduces to:

$$3^n - 3\cdot2^n + 3$$

The solution comes to me as follows. There are $3\cdot2^n$ configurations that are illegal because they only use $2$ colors. Of these, some are counted more than once so let's take a closer look:

$$2^n\,\{B, C\}\qquad\qquad2^n\,\{A, C\}\qquad\qquad2^n\,\{A, B\}\qquad\qquad$$

All the formations you can make with **EXACTLY** two colors are unique and counted only once. How about all the formations you can make with **EXACTLY** one color? Well that answer is obviously ${{3}\choose{1}}$ but let's see how many times we have overcounted by subtracting $3\cdot2^n$. Just like we broke up $3^n$ into our $3\cdot2^n$ formations with two colors, let's break up each $2^n$ into $2$ single color $1^n$ formations and see if we have any repeats!

$$2^n\,\{B, C\}\qquad\qquad2^n\,\{A, C\}\qquad\qquad2^n\,\{A, B\}\qquad\qquad$$

\begin{array}{cc}
\text{Each of the $2^n$ can make 2 single color sets so we will have repeats:}\\
\hline
\end{array}

$$1^n\,\{B\}\qquad\qquad\qquad1^n\,\{A\}\qquad\qquad\qquad\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{1^n\,\{A\}}$$
$$1^n\,\{C\}\qquad\qquad\qquad\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{1^n\,\{C\}}\qquad\qquad\qquad\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{1^n\,\{B\}}$$

You can see that there are obviously only ${{3}\choose{1}}$ unique illegal single color formations, however we've accounted for each one twice by subtracting $3\cdot2^n$ from $3^n$ so we must add back the ones we overcounted. This is why we add back a ${{3}\choose{1}}$. If we overcounted each unique single color formation by 100, I believe we would add back 100 to the final answer so we could be left with only the unique single color formations that are illegal.

I was working on the following problem:

How many ways to color n objects with 4 colors $\{A, B, C, D\}$, if all colors must be used at least once.

Following the same logic in [this post's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680507/color-combination-problem), the following process makes sense to me:

Total number of ways to color N objects with any colors would be $4^n$. Of the $4^n$, there are:

$$3^n\,\text{that use only}\,\{B, C, D\},\;3^n\,\text{that use only}\,\{A, C, D\},\;3^n\,\text{that use only}\,\{A, B, C\}$$

This givs us ${{4}\choose{3}}\cdot3^n$ invalid options. However this over-counts several invalid options several times. Let's take a closer look.
$$3^n\, \{B, C, D\}\qquad3^n\, \{A, C, D\}\qquad3^n\, \{A, B, D\}\qquad3^n\, \{A, B, C\}$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\text{Which breaks down to the following (${{4}\choose{2}}$duplicates crossed out):}\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$2^n\,\{B, C\}\qquad\qquad2^n\,\{A, C\}\qquad\qquad2^n\,\{A, B\}\qquad\qquad\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{2^n\,\{A, B\}}$$
$$2^n\,\{B, D\}\qquad\qquad2^n\,\{A, D\}\qquad\qquad\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{2^n\,\{A, D\}}\qquad\qquad\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{2^n\,\{A, C\}}$$
$$2^n\,\{C, D\}\qquad\qquad\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{2^n\,\{C, D\}}\qquad\qquad\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{2^n\,\{B, D\}}\qquad\qquad\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{2^n\,\{B, C\}}$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\text{Which breaks down to the following:}\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$2^n\,\{B, C\}\quad2^n\,\{B, D\}\quad2^n\,\{C, D\}\quad2^n\,\{A, C\}\quad2^n\,\{A, D\}\quad2^n\,\{A, B\}$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\text{Since all $2^n$ are unique, the only sets that we count many times here are the one with one letter}\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$1^n\,\{B\}\qquad\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{1^n\,\{B\}}\qquad\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{1^n\,\{C\}}\qquad1^n\,\{A\}\qquad\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{1^n\,\{A\}}\qquad\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{1^n\,\{A\}}$$
$$1^n\,\{C\}\qquad1^n\,\{D\}\qquad\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{1^n\,\{D\}}\qquad\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{1^n\,\{C\}}\qquad\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{1^n\,\{D\}}\qquad\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{1^n\,\{B\}}$$

We obviously know that there are going to be only 4 unique countings of 1 letter sets since there are only 4 colors, so the other 8 were counted many times, just like the other 6 sets of $2^n$

To me, this makes the answer:

$$4^n - {{4}\choose{3}}\cdot3^n + {{4}\choose{2}}\cdot2^n + 8\cdot1^n$$

I am slightly suspicious as it doesn't follow the pattern that would make ${{4}\choose{1}}\cdot1^n$ be the last term, however walking through the logic it is clear to me that just as we counted 6 of the $2^n$ sets twice, we are counting, the monochromatic sets 8 extra times than necessary, so we need to give them back so I believe my first solution is correct? Could someone verify my logic here?

Comment: Seems fine to me...

Comment: @SayantanSantra Ok, is there some other way to get $8\cdot1^n$ without opening it up and seeing exactly how many are being repeated, I feel like there might be some pattern I missed here that could help expand it for a general case

Comment: I cannot bet on it but I see a pattern. It's like $r^n-{r \choose r-1} \cdot (r-1)^n+\sum_{i=1}^{r-2}{2^{r-2-i}{r \choose i} \cdot i^n}$

Comment: Ok I was curious if there was some factor of 2 that might be present in this, which your summation shows. I understand that that's not a proven method by any means but thanks for showing that. So I guess the last term "MIGHT" be, $2^1\cdot{{4}\choose{1}}\cdot1^n$ = $8\cdot1^n$

Comment: Yeah... That's exactly what made me cook up the summation...

Comment: @SayantanSantra well perhaps if I really feel like doing the work I'll try it out for r = 5 colors

Comment: Yeah... Go on...

Comment: Your formula doesn't give $24$ for $n=4$.

Comment: If anything it was more correct as the first version with the power of 2. I'll try and double check tomorrow though

Comment: I have added an answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $$4^n-\binom{4}{3}\cdot3^n+\binom{4}{2}2^n-\binom{4}{1}1^n$$

Any coloring that uses *exactly* 3 colors is subtracted from the $4^n$ total colorings *once* in the $-\binom{4}{3}\cdot3^n$ term. That coloring only appears in one of the $\binom{4}{3}$ collections of colorings, and it is only one of that collection's $3^n$ colorings.

Any coloring that uses *exactly* 2 colors (for example, an $\{A,B\}$-coloring) is subtracted from the $4^n$ total colorings *twice* in the $-\binom{4}{3}\cdot3^n$ term (as one of the $\{A,B,C\}$-colorings and as one of the $\{A,B,D\}$-colorings), then added back *once* in the $+\binom{4}{2}2^n$ term (as one of the $\{A,B\}$-colorings). The net effect is to subtract it once from the $4^n$ total.

Any coloring that uses *exactly* 1 color (for example, the all-$A$ coloring) is subtracted from the $4^n$ total colorings *three times* in the $-\binom{4}{3}\cdot3^n$ term (as one of the $\{A,B,C\}$-colorings, as one of the $\{A,B,D\}$-colorings, and as one of the $\{A,C,D\}$-colorings), then added back *three times* in the $+\binom{4}{2}2^n$ term (as one of the $\{A,B\}$-colorings, as one of the $\{A,C\}$-colorings, and as one of the $\{A,D\}$-colorings), and then subtracted again *once* in the $-\binom{4}{1}1^n$ term (as the $\{A\}$-coloring). The net effect is to subtract it once from the $4^n$ total.

This is all an example of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

---

Written as $$\binom{4}{4}4^n-\binom{4}{3}\cdot3^n+\binom{4}{2}2^n-\binom{4}{1}1^n+\binom{4}{0}\cdot0^n$$ you can directly verify that this gives correct results for $n=0,1,2,3,4$.

---

For $r$ colors, the same logic gives the formula $$\sum_{k=0}^r\binom{r}{r-k}(-1)^k(r-k)^n$$ which is equivalent (by reindexing $k\mapsto r-k$) to $$\sum_{k=0}^r\binom{r}{k}(-1)^{r-k}k^n$$

Comment: Can you please extend it for $r$ choices of colours?

Comment: I feel like there is an error in your last paragraph. We don't want to subtract it JUST once from the total, $4^n$, we want to subtract it ALL but once from the total, so that were only counting it one time and one time only. So we leave that one case with the $4^n$ and subtract the rest that are counted multiple times

Comment: @DomFarolino I don't follow you. The count $4^n$ includes the _one_ instance where everything is colored $A$. The $-\binom{4}{3}\cdot3^n$ subtracts three colorings where everything is colored $A$. The $+\binom{4}{2}\cdot2^n$ adds back three colorings where everything is colored $A$. Finally, $-\binom{4}{1}\cdot1^n$ subtracts one coloring where everything is colored $A$. The net is that no all-$A$ colorings are counted. We have subtracted a net of _one_ all-$A$ coloring from the one that was included with the $4^n$ count.

Comment: I expanded the wording, in case that helps.

Comment: @alex.jordan Ok so I understand that each solution using exactly 3 colors has been subtracted once...each solution using exactly two colors have been subtracted twice, as shows my table in the question that has the repeated $2^n$ sets stricken out. Then you say each set using exactly 1 color has been subtracted once. This is where I lose you. I see each one being subtracted 3 times from each of the unique $2^n$ sets, when we only need to subtract them once. So to make up for this, we need to add back two of each color, that we over-counted.

Comment: @alex.jordan Similarly to how in my table in the question, we added back the stricken out duplicate $2^n$ sets, we have to add back the stricken out $1^n$ sets that were overcounted...exactly 8 of the 12 single color ($1^n$) sets formed from the unique $2^n$ sets are not unique so we must add them back...This is my rationale if that makes any sense

Comment: With $n=4$, $\binom{4}{4}4^4$ counts $\{\color{blue}{AAAA},AAAB,\ldots,ABCD,\ldots,DDDD\}$. Note the _one_ instance of $\color{blue}{AAAA}$.

Comment: Then $-\binom{4}{3}3^4$ counts $\{\color{blue}{AAAA},AAAB,\ldots,ABCC,\ldots,CCCC\}\sqcup\{\color{blue}{AAAA}, AAAB\ldots,ABDD,\ldots,DDDD\}\sqcup\{\color{blue}{AAAA},AAAC,\ldots,ACDD,\ldots,DDDD\}\sqcup\{BBBB,BBBC,\ldots,BCDD,\ldots,DDDD\}$. Note the _three_ instances of $\color{blue}{AAAA}$.

Comment: Then $+\binom{4}{2}2^4$ counts $\{\color{blue}{AAAA},AAAB,\ldots,BBBB\}\sqcup\{\color{blue}{AAAA},AAAC,\ldots,CCCC\}\sqcup\{\color{blue}{AAAA},AAAD,\ldots,DDDD\}\sqcup\{BBBB,BBBC,\ldots,CCCC\}\sqcup\{BBBB,BBBD,\ldots,DDDD\}\sqcup\{CCCC,CCCD,\ldots,DDDD\}$. Note the _three_ instances of $\color{blue}{AAAA}$.

Comment: Lastly, $-\binom{4}{1}1^4$ counts $\{\color{blue}{AAAA}\}\sqcup\{BBBB\}\sqcup\{CCCC\}\sqcup\{DDDD\}$. All together, $1-3+3-1=0$. This is all the effort I can make trying to explain it differently. I'm sorry if this isn't enough, but if you still don't see it, at least convince yourself that your approach is not working because it fails to give $24$ for $n=4$.

Comment: @alex.jordan . I appreciate it thanks a lot. I think that makes sense. I was seeing the $4^n$ as overcounting each single color set by 8, not just counting it once. I re-layed out my thought process for the n=3 problem in the question, which incidentally yields the right answer but seemingly by mistake. My original thought process was wrong. Thanks so much

Comment: Cool. If you haven't already, read up on the link to the inclusion-exclusion principle. It makes this kind of thing easy in the future.